# Initialize Array in Class - Swift

Tags: swift

I am strugeling to work with the array accounts, I don't really know how I should handle it, how I should initialize it in order to correctly append the object accountFromJohn to the list accounts.

```
class Bank {
    var bicCode : String
    var address : String
    var customer : Customer
    var accounts : [BankAccount] = []
    init(bicCode : String, address : String, customer : Customer) {
        self.bicCode = bicCode
        self.address = address
        self.customer = customer
    }
}

var accountFromJohn = BankAccount(accountNumber : 192, balance : 20, customer : John)
var ING = Bank(bicCode : "LUING18", address : "Avenue du Swing", customer : Paul)

ING.accounts.append(accountFromJohn)

print(ING.accounts) // output : [main.BankAccount] ; wanted output : [accountFromJohn]
```

Best Reagars,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `accountFromJohn` is a variable name. Variable names exist purely for human interpretation, and don't exist at all at runtime. The `BankAccount` instance that's called `accountFromJohn` is actually some memory address, or some set of CPU registers. The program is telling you that `ING.accounts` contains one instance of type `main.BankAccount`. It doesn't know anything about whether you choose to call that instance `accountFromJohn` or `magicUnicornRainbowPoops`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine.

The array contains an instance of `BankAccount` rather than an arbitrary variable name `accountFromJohn`.

Prove it by printing

```
print(ING.accounts.first?.customer ?? "Accounts is empty")
```

---

However it's possible to print `accountFromJohn`. in `BankAccount` adopt `CustomStringConvertible` and add the property

```
var description : String {
    return "accountFrom\(customer)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this as one approach you can assign values to **accounts** while initialisation of objects.

```
class Bank {
    var bicCode : String
    var address : String
    var customer : Customer
    var accounts : [BankAccount]
    init(bicCode : String, address : String, customer : Customer, accounts: [BankAccount]) {
        self.bicCode = bicCode
        self.address = address
        self.customer = customer
        self.accounts = accounts
    }
}
```

Then you can work with the objects properly.

```
var accountFromJohn = [BankAccount(accountNumber : 192, balance : 20, customer : John)]
var ING = Bank(bicCode : "LUING18", address : "Avenue du Swing", customer : Paul, accounts: accountFromJohn)
```

And then you can append data to **Bank** list like `yourObject.append(ING)`, if you want to change values of accounts, you can do it by `yourObject[desiredElement].accounts.append(accountsData)` and if you need to retrieve values `yourObject[desiredElement].accounts`